# add a Place label inside the second Country

Tags: c#, wpf, class, dictionary

If I have been researching this correctly, I got some help before and a user said that it would be good to use a `Dictionary` to store my `Country` and `Places`.

So I create my `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, NewCountryClass> NTCD = new Dictionary<string, NewcountryClass>();
```

When the user clicks the button it will trigger this class where I wanted it to create a instance of `newCountryClass` inside the `Dictionary` at runtime. It would add the string which would be the `newCountryTitle.Country` and then the `Class`.

```
public void AddCountryCollection()
{

    newCountryClass = new NewCountryClass(newCountry,"");
    Collections.Add(newCountryClass);
    NTCD.Add(newCountryClass.Country, newCountryClass);
}
```

So lets say the user has has added the `Country` which has created this `Dictionary` at Runtime, and they have added 4 `Countries`, but now want to go back and add a `Place` label inside the second Country.

This is the `newCountryClass`:

```
private string _country;

public string Country
{
   get { return _country; }
   set
   {
      if (_country.Equals(value))
         return;

      _country= value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => Country);
   }
}

private ICollection<string> _places;
public ICollection<string> Places
{
   get
   {
      if (_places== null)
         _places= new ObservableCollection<string>();
      return _places;
   }
   set
   {
      if (value == _places)
         return;

      _places= value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => Places);
   }
}
```

If they have created 4, and they want to add a `Place` to the list inside that `Country` of the **second** one they created, how would I find it?

Comment: consider using [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) , looks like it's the only way. However it's not generic. The performance may be slightly worse than the normal generic Dictionary.

Comment: Also this question should not be such long. It should be ***just some lines long***. Why? the problem is just ***how to get the second element of a Dictionary***. That's all. Asking question like this will make ***many users*** (including experts) ignore the question (we are normally afraid of long questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer I simply use the key I stored:

```
NTCD["GER"].Places.Add("New Place inside GER");
```

If I only want to know the second one, either take a `List<NewCountryClass>` and iterate by index with foror take a [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx). It takes object key, object value as parameters on add and I can access it via `NTCD[3]`.